# Sinch Answering call directly onclick on local notification like viber

Tags: android, ios, sinch

I have successfully integrated Sinch SDK and its working great when the App is open, now i am handling the call when my app is closed.

When the App is closed , there is local notification on incoming call when i click on notification it will come to call screen and there we press "answer " or "decline" , but what i need is when we click on the notification i want to establish call directly without asking for "answer" or "decline" .

I tried calling method in **Appdelegate.m**-

```
   - (void)handleLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification  
    {
        CallViewController *obj=[CallViewController alloc];
        double delayInSeconds =2.0;
             dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
             dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [obj answeCallDireclty];
                 NSLog(@"Answer  ");

      });
```

**CallViewController.m**

```
-(void)answeCallDireclty
{
    [self.call answer];
}

- (IBAction)accept:(id)sender {
 //   [[self audioController] stopPlayingSoundFile];
    [self.call answer];

}
```

Control will reach to answerCallDireclty(); method but the call is not established, call will get establisehd only when i press "Answer" button.

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario it may be dependent on how you handle the `-[SINCallClient client:didReceiveIncomingCall:]` callback that I assume in this case is assigning a SINCall to your `call` property on the view controller. E.g. once the application return to foreground, that delegate method will be invoked which gives you the opportunity to assign the SINCall to your `call` property on your view controller, on which you then can invoke `-[SINCall answer]`.

When you reach your method `answerCallDirectly`, are you sure `self.call` is assigned yet, and not nil?

(You should also relay the local notification to the Sinch SDK via the method `-[SINClient relayLocalNotification:]`, but in this particular case I don't think that is the issue)

Comment: self.call is not nil , i can see that in debug but still the call is not getting answered , it gets answered only when i press button .